# SQLAlchemy Delete Persistency Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For some reason the code below is generating a persistency error:

```
'<Data at 0x1041db8d0>' is not persisted
```

Does the object need to be initialized before it's deleted, what's wrong here?

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form3.validate():
    data_entered = Data(notes=form3.dbDelete.data)
    try:
        db.session.delete(data_entered)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()
        return render_template('deleted.html', notes=form3.dbDelete.data)
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_entered = Data(notes=form3.dbDelete.data)`

This is creating a new instance (or row) of `Data`. Then you are running a `session.delete` procedure to remove it from the database, but it never was inserted (via `session.commit()` for example).

I'm guessing this is what you are trying to do:

```
try:
    data_entered = db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.notes == form3.dbDelete.data).one()
except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound:
    pass
else:
    try:
        db.session.delete(data_entered)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()
        return render_template('deleted.html', notes=form3.dbDelete.data)
```